# How can I control an iOS device from my computer?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

My iOS device is cracked and is not working properly. It got me thinking: Is there a way to control an iOS device from my computer?  I know that I can use Quicktime to view the screen but it doesn't allow me to actually control it. I am open to third party programs.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by controlling it with your computer?